# New exe icon not reflecting in windows 7 task bar for vb6

Tags: vb6, exe, taskbar

I changed the resource file for a new icon for my exe and generated the exe for vb6 project. However, the exe icon has changed but the windows 7 task bar is still showing the old icon.
If I generate the exe in some other location other than my project directory its working fine. Could someone please help on this issue?

Comment: It happens to me, I think it is a bug of Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Windows you updated the icon so it can update its cache.

If you're using VB6, make yourself a little utility:

- Create a new EXE project (name it "ForceIconsRefresh" or something like that)
- In the project properties, change the *Startup Object* to "Sub Main"
- Add a new module, remove the default Form object
- In the module add the following:

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function SHChangeNotify Lib "Shell32.dll" (ByVal wEventID As Long, ByVal uFlags As Long, ByVal dwItem1 As Long, ByVal dwItem2 As Long) As Long
Private Const SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED As Long = &H8000000
Private Const SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT As Long = &H2000

Sub Main()
    Call SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

- Compile
- Execute after building an EXE with an updated icon

Voilà!